# Mobile wallet that supports importing single address?

Tags: wallet, private-key-import, mobile

Is there a mobile wallet that supports importing a single address (public key) / private key pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electrum on Android allows you to import address as watch-only or a private key:

[image: electrum-android]

FullyNoded on iOS can be used to import private key, xprv or descriptor: https://github.com/Fonta1n3/FullyNoded/blob/master/Docs/Wallets/Recovery.md